# jquery to pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, toggle

Есть код на jquery (Смотрите ниже) который работает как нужно.

Но очень хочется посмотреть как это будет выглядеть на чистом JS. Если кто сможет помочь сделать это буду очень благодарен.

Потратив не малое количество часов пришел к такому такому варианту и не могу продвинуться дальше.

```js
var pickGame = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
var opWindow = document.querySelector(".container");
console.log(pickGame);
pickGame.forEach(function(aitem, aindex) {
  aitem.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var thisitem = this;
    console.log(this.matches(".opened"));
    thisitem.classList.toggle("opened");
    opWindow.classList.toggle("opened");

    if (this.matches(".opened")) {
      opWindow.classList.remove("opened");
    }
    pickGame.forEach(function(bitem, bindex) {
      if (thisitem !== bitem) {
        bitem.classList.remove("opened");
        opWindow.classList.remove("opened");
        setTimeout(() => {
          opWindow.classList.add("opened");
        }, 300);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon-container {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-210px);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon.opened {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.container.opened {
  transform: translateX(90px);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>1st</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>2nd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>3rd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>4th</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Рабочий вариант с JQUERY

```js
$('.icon').click(function() {
  if ($('.icon').not(this).hasClass("opened")) {
    $('.icon').not(this).removeClass("opened");
    $(this).toggleClass("opened");
    $('.container').toggleClass("opened");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.container').toggleClass("opened");
    }, 300);
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass("opened");
    $('.container').toggleClass("opened");
  };
})

var iconInd = $('.icon');
var contentInd = $('.content');

iconInd.each(function(indexIcon) {
  iconInd.eq(indexIcon).click(function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      contentInd.eq(indexIcon).toggleClass("visible");
    }, 300);
    contentInd.each(function(indexContent) {
      if (indexContent !== indexIcon) {
        contentInd.eq(indexContent).removeClass("visible");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon-container {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-210px);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon.opened {
  border-radius: 10px!important;
}

.container.opened {
  transform: translateX(90px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>1st</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>2nd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>3rd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>4th</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно, ссылка не рабочая, выложите код jQ сюда, расскажите по-подробнее, что у вас не получилось, где возникла проблема с переводом

Comment: добавил JQ сюда

Comment: Закрытие выезжающего окна при клике на туже иконку (Окно закрывается и снова открывается),после этого проблемы с добавлением разного контента в выезжающее окно в зависимости на какую иконку кликаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let pickGame = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
let opWindow = document.querySelector('.container');
let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

content.forEach(function(aitem, aindex, arr) {
  pickGame[aindex].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!content[aindex].classList.contains('visible')) {
      content.forEach((aitem, aindex) => {
        aitem.classList.remove('visible');
        pickGame[aindex].classList.remove('opened');

      });
      aitem.classList.add('visible');
      pickGame[aindex].classList.add('opened');
      opWindow.classList.remove("opened");
      setTimeout(() => {
        opWindow.classList.add("opened");
      }, 300);
    } else {
      aitem.classList.remove('visible');
      pickGame[aindex].classList.remove('opened');
      opWindow.classList.remove("opened");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon-container {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-210px);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease .6s;
}

.icon.opened {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.container.opened {
  transform: translateX(90px);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>1st</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>2nd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>3rd</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>4th</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БРАТ!!!! <3

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста....